# Trouble executing model file using pyomo for 2-stage SLP

Tags: python, optimization, cplex, pyomo

I am currently reading the manual on pyomo to learn how to use Python with a solver like cplex/gurobi to solve 2-stage Stochastic Linear Program. But I am struggled to execute the **concrete model** provided in this github (https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/tree/master/examples/pysp/farmer)

for the Farmer's problem using either the command line: `runph --model-directory=models --instance-directory=nodedata --default-rho=1` or `pyomo solve --solver=cplex ReferenceModel.py AverageScenario.dat`. My Python's version is `3.5`, and my `cplex` install in Annaconda is version `3.5`.

The error message is

```
ERROR: Unexpected exception while running model:
        No executable found for solver 'cplex'
```

**My question:** How to change the directory path by command line so that it could look for `cplex` solver? I am using Annaconda to run the command line `!pyomo solve --solver=cplex ReferenceModel.py AverageScenario.dat`. The path that contains my `ReferenceModel.py` and `nodedata` is: `Users/[myname]/pyomo-master/models/ReferenceModel.py`. I already put all the data files into the same folder as `ReferenceModel.py`, but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message it sounds like pyomo is unable to find the `cplex.exe` executable. According to the [pyomo documentation](https://software.sandia.gov/downloads/pub/pyomo/PyomoInstallGuide.html#_cplex):

> the directory containing the cplex executable must be in the list of
>   paths defined by the PATH environment variable

For example, to do this in a console window (temporarily) you would do something like this:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;"C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio128\cplex\bin\x64_win64"
```

To set the PATH environement vartiable permanently see [here](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml), for example.